# Convert String into Set<Object>

Tags: java, string, set

I'm having a string like below

**MyString**

```
[{"id":123,"name":"Abc"},{"id":124,"name":"EDF"}]
```

I need to convert/map this into my class(Test) using Set

**Test**

```
public class Test {
    int id;
String name;
}
```

I've tried with the following method but didn't get succeed.

```
    Set<Test> meds = (Set<Test>) (Object) MyString;
```

The Exception is

> > java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Set

Comment: String to Set directly ? That is not possible. You need to build your objects from String first.

Comment: Please convert the String into objects first. then you can pass them. second option you can convert the string in to Json format and use the Object Mapper in the Code part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jackson library for convertation your String to Set of objects.

You cannot convert it directly.

```
TypeReference<Set<Test>> ref = new TypeReference<Set<Test>>() {};
try {
    new ObjectMapper().readValue("[{\"id\":123,\"name\":\"Abc\"},{\"id\":124,\"name\":\"EDF\"}]", ref);
} catch (IOException ignored) {
    // stub
}
```

And of course do not forgot to add getters and setters into your Test class

Answer (score 0):

This is a json object, you will need to use a parser. Look into GSON, for example.